# `. shortcut doesn't expand to \cdot

Tags: vim, vim-latex

According to latex-suite documentation, `` `. `` should expand into `\cdot` but this is not working for me. All other abbreviations (greek letters and math) do work.
I tried looking in `~/.vim/ftplugin/main.vim` and it seems to look fine:

```
call IMAP (g:Tex_Leader.'.', '\cdot', "tex")
```

or at least it is identical to the other `` ` `` abbreviations setup. I looked in `wizardfuncs.vim`, `mathmacros.vim` and `mathmacros-utf.vim` (all in the `~/.vim/ftplugin/` path), since I do not know which file vim actually reads, and there are the lines:

```
\."\n `.     \\cdot             `*     \\times"

exe s:pA8.'cdot<Tab>`.              <plug>\

exe s:pA8.'cdot<Tab>`.\ \ ⋅              <plug>\cdot '
```

respectively, which are no different from other abbreviations format. Even putting manually

```
call IMAP('`.', '\\cdot', 'tex')
```

in `~/.vimrc` doesn't manage to resolve.

I know it's not that big an issue, but I was getting sort of curious as to why `` `. `` is unmanageable...

Comment: Seems like a bug. It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Idem: it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a conflict with the [smart dots key mapping](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/smart-keys.html) that automatically replaces `...` with `\cdots`, `\ldots` or `\dots` as appropriate. If you disable this feature by adding

```
let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot=0
```

to `$VIMFILES/ftplugin/tex.vim`, then the key mapping works as intended.

This happens because of the way that the `SmartDots()` function is implemented: vim-latex watches for any `.` inserted and, if there are only 1 or 2 consecutive dots, the function returns `.` or `..`, respectively. When it sees three consecutive dots, it inserts the appropriate 'dots' macro. This seems to override any of the IMAP mappings because the last `.` was not inserted by the user, but was instead returned by the function. You can also test this by adding a mapping such as

```
call IMAP('TEST.', 'test', 'tex')
```

which does not work whenever smart dots is enabled.

If you use either the `amsmath` or `ellipsis` package, then `\dots` is all you will need. To use the ``.` key mapping, you can simply add

```
let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot=0
call IMAP('...', '\dots', 'tex')
```

to `$VIMFILES/ftplugin/tex.vim`.